# Visual Studio 2017 C++, How to define an 'Additional Library Directory' that is an 'Environment Variable'?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, environment-variables

I use Boost. Installation directory is: `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0`, and the 'Environment Variable' `$BOOST_ROOT` defined with accordance. When I set an 'Additional Library Directory' as full-path, VS recognizes the path. Is there a way to use the 'Environment Variable'?

Comment: I suggest to use workspace-based approach rather than environment variables. It would be less troublesome to track dependencies and use different boost version at the same time.

Comment: I had that dilemma in mind. Boost Website "getting_started/windows" says: **"1. The path to the boost root directory (often `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0`) is sometimes referred to as `$BOOST_ROOT` in documentation and mailing lists"**. I prefer to stick to the documentation, & to use the latest version only (of Boost). I.e. as a rule: `BOOST_ROOT` refers to the latest version. If, in the future, a situation will rise, it is possible, under `C:\Program Files\boost` to populate another version of Boost.

Comment: That guide does not suggest to use environment variables though. The problem with environment variables is that they are basically "super global" variables. They may be changed from anywhere, reused for unrelated purposes and are troublesome to debug when things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** VS doesn't recognizes 'Additional Library Directory' `$(BOOST_ROOT)` i.e. referred by an 'Environment Variable' `BOOST_ROOT`. I defined the 'Environment Variable' while VS is running. **Fix:** After restart the computer, VS recognizes `$(BOOST_ROOT)`.

Comment: This is understandable as VS inherited the environment variables from from it's parent process before `BOOST_ROOT` was created.  A simpler fix should be just restarting VS after `BOOST_ROOT` has been created.

Comment: @RichardCritten not necessarily, if you start visual studio from explorer (either from the start menu, desktop shortcut or opening a file) then VS will inherit its environment from explorer, you need to log out to update explorer's environment variables then start VS.

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables can be used in VS properties just like [VS property macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/working-with-project-properties#bkmkPropertiesVersusMacros) can. So just set the Additional Library Directory property to

```
$(BOOST_ROOT)\whatever_is\necessary
```

Comment: Is that true?  The last time I tried that (which was before VS 2017 came along) it didn't work.

Comment: @PaulSanders It doesn't work in your version? We are using this at least since VS2003 without problems...

Comment: @ezi Strange indeed. It works just fine for me in VS2013 (just tested in a fresh project).

Comment: @ezi are you sure the environment variable is defined? Note that process environment variables are inherited from their parent process. This means that for example if you start a process by clicking an icon in explorer or the start menu then that process will have whatever the environment variables were set to when you logged in.

Comment: @king_nak It definitely didn't work when I last tried it.  That might have been in VS 2010, I don't recall.  The reason I recollect so vividly is that prior to that I was using [Joshua Jensen's Worskpace Whiz](http://workspacewhiz.com/) to set these and when VS 2010 (or whatever it was) came out my macros stopped working.  But I did raise a bug report so maybe MS have got round to fixing it.  I now use a different mechanism so I no longer know.

Comment: @ezi note that if you click the "Macros>>" button in the value editor this should list all the environment variables

Comment: @AlanBirtles OK. I restarted the computer after defining the 'Environment Variable', and in VS works with `$(BOOST_ROOT)`.

Comment: @ezi Logging out and back in again will do it.

Answer (score -1):

I think environment variables, unlike VS macros and variables, are expanded with `%%`, so path should be:

```
%BOOST_ROOT%\whatever
```

Since msbuild also treats `%` as a beginning of hex char escape sequence (and performs substitution prior to environment variable expansion) it may be necessary to escape `%` with `%25`.

Comment: No, you use brackets as with other variables https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms171459.aspx. The only time you can use percent is when using environment variables in command lines (e.g. post build events)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm talking about VS2017. In this VS version `%%` are properly expanded when used inside of additional include dirs and other file system related properties.

Comment: really? I've just tested it and for example `%DEFAULT%` seems to be expanded to `ÞFAULT%` so if it is supported its buggy, the 2017 documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build

Comment: @AlanBirtles Really... Not sure why you are getting `ÞFAULT%`. Maybe it is a problem with a way you set environment variable. Try using some predefined ones, such as `%APPDATA%`.

Comment: because visual studio uses % for hex character literals not environment variables.

Comment: @AlanBirtles If the name of environment variable starts with msbuild escape sequence then it can be fixed by using escapes for `%`. For example `%DEFAULT%` should be `%25DEFAULT%25`